# Why won't the code hide the html div when the argument (false) is entered in the winOrNot function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Why does this code not hide the "Congratulations" message in the div when the function is called with the (false) argument?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="winner">Congratulations!</div>
<script>
var winner = function winOrNot(winner) {
//if the variable winner has the value of true, show the div with id "winner"
if(winner) {
    document.getElementById('winner');
}
//otherwise, hide the div if the value of winner is false
else {
    document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'none';
}

winOrNot(false);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: Thank you for your suggestions. I have updated my code with your ideas, but I still get the same result after saving the edits and running the code. Here is the revision:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<style>
    #winner {
        display:block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="winner">Congratulations!</div>
<script>
var winner = function winner(winner) {
//if the variable winner has the value of true, show the div with id "winner"
    if(winner) {
    document.getElementById('winner');
}
//otherwise, hide the div if the value of winner is false
    if(winner===false) {
    document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'none';
}

}
winner(false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Calling `winOrNot(false);` _inside_ the function will create an infinite loop. Don’t name the function variable the same name as the parameter. `document.getElementById('winner');` does not do anything.

Comment: Thank you Xufox! Having a different name for the variable other than the parameter name solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the function `winOrNot`. your function **call** (`winOrNot(false)`) was inside the declaration of `winOrNot`.

Also, in order to change the state back from `display: none`, we need to set `display: block` on the element we hid.

```js
winOrNot(false);

setTimeout(() => winOrNot(true), 2000);

function winOrNot(winner) {
  //if the variable winner has the value of true, show the div with id "winner"
  if (winner) {
    document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'block';
  }
  //otherwise, hide the div if the value of winner is false
  else {
    document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<h5>should change after 5 seconds</h5>

<div id="winner">Congratulations!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `winner(winner)` and not `winOrNot(winner)`. Also move the call `winner(false)` outside function definition(Better indentation of code helps to identify such problems).

```js
var winner = function winOrNot(winner) {
//if the variable winner has the value of true, show the div with id "winner"
if(winner) {
    document.getElementById('winner');
}
//otherwise, hide the div if the value of winner is false
else {
    document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'none';
}
}

winner(false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="winner">Congratulations!</div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you're trying to call this function call this with `winner()` coz this is where you're saving this function reference.

Secondly you are not calling this in your script.

You need to do that outside the function body. And if you're trying to specify the name of the function in function expression, then name would only be available inside the function body. (in case you need to do recursive calls.) But if you don't need anything like that, either create an anonymous function or named function. So, you may call it simply,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="winner">Congratulations!</div>
<script>
var winner = function winOrNot(winner) {
//if the variable winner has the value of true, show the div with id "winner"
if(winner) {
    document.getElementById('winner');
}
//otherwise, hide the div if the value of winner is false
else {
    document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'none';
}


}
winner(false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var winner = function winOrNot(winner) {
//if the variable winner has the value of true, show the div with id "winner"
if(winner) {
    document.getElementById('winner');
}
//otherwise, hide the div if the value of winner is false
else {
    document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'none';
}
}

  setTimeout(function(){ winner(false);}, 3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="winner">Congratulations!</div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `winOrNot` was not run! Now let us review your scripts

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>you can c</div>
<div id="winner">Congratulations!</div>
<script>
var winner = function winOrNot(winner) {
  // if the variable winner has the value of true, show the div with id "winner"
  if(winner) {
    document.getElementById('winner');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('winner').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
winner(false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are't the execute about `winOrNot`. You put the `winOrNot(false)` into the function itself. Maybe put it outside can see what you want.

And function `winOrNot` is not define when you called outside, so you have to call `winner`.

One more thing, you created a recursive function and infinite recursion that there is a only situation that the stack more than max stack.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by stack more than max stack? I updated the code but running the function still causes the output to be "Congratulations" whether the argument is true or false